# ADF Pipeline connects to SQL via private endpoint OK, but a second pipeline it invokes does not

Tags: azure-data-factory

Have this ADF issue:

Got a pipeline. It does an SQL operation on a SQL connection. It uses an integration runtime with a private endpoint, as the deny public connection setting is enabled. Hence, we use a private endpoint. Lots of faff to get that working but it works.

Run the pipeline, first operation is to run an SQL script that truncates a tables. Success. Second one deletes the tables. Success. Third one creates tables. Success.

Fourth operation is to run another pipeline.

So pipeline 2 runs, first operation is a COPY operation from oracle to sql.

This fails with the error:

> Operation on target Copy TheTable Table failed:
> ErrorCode=SqlDeniedPublicAccess,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot
> connect to SQL Database: '.redacted...windows.net', Database:
> 'MyDatabase', Reason: Connection was denied since Deny Public Network
> Access is set to Yes. To connect to this server, 1. If you persist
> public network access disabled, please use Managed Virtual Network IR
> and create private endpoint.
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint;
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private;
> 2. Otherwise you can enable public network access, set "Public network access" option to "Selected networks" on Auzre SQL Networking
> setting.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Thing is, we did this. We had to do this to get it working at all. If I go and hit test connection, it works. If I choose one of my COPY operations, and press 'preview data', I can see the oracle data, and I can see the (empty) sql table data. No errors.

So why is the sub-pipeline that the first pipeline calls causing this issue?

I've checked the Json, it's configured identically to the other pipelines. In fact, I run this exact configuration on 3 other environments (without using private endpoint) and all of them work fine.

I'm absolutely at a loss for what it could be. I can only think it's some quirk of the copy operation, since the direct script-running operations worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Solution at end)

This is an old question but the only one I found and we experienced this today, so posting for anyone in the future who comes up against this.

Context:

- Exact same error, though it was on a lookup not a copy, but same same.
- Dev and test environments working fine.
- Separate production Data Factory connecting fine.
- All on private endpoints using AutoResolve IR.
- No changes to any settings or deployments, there was no obvious reason for it to not work.

Solution:

We put it down to  "Mystery Microsoft bug", created a new AutoResolve IR and updated the activity, bam no further issue.